# Yocto: Difference between CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL and IMAGE_INSTALL

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Recently, I tried to include open source package (iperf3) to target image via Yocto build. (Updating local.conf for `IMAGE_INSTALL += "iperf3"`, as the project already corresponding recipe).
But the final image did not include in root file system.

I tried the same by adding to package group recipe in `<DistroMetaLayer>/recipe-core/packagegroups/RDEPENDS_packagegroup*` and was able to include it successfully.

Can someone provide me explanation for the behavior.

Answer (score 8):

When you write `IMAGE_INSTALL += "iperf3"` in your local.conf, that will immediately add `iperf3` to `IMAGE_INSTALL`. If your image adds the base rootfs by doing `IMAGE_INSTALL ?= "...."`, then that default value will never be added, as `IMAGE_INSTALL` already have a value.

If you want to modify `IMAGE_INSTALL` from local.conf (and a lot other variables), you should always do that with a delayed append / prepend. I.e.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " iperf3"
```

Note the leading space.

Comment: Thanks..it worked for me..Does IMAGE_INSTALL += " iperf3" is not same as IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " iperf3" , even with leading space to both of them