# What's the difference between IMAGE_INSTALL and CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL

Tags: yocto

It seems both (**IMAGE_INSTALL** and **CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL**) can add packages into yocto image.

What's their difference?

I checked this issue:

[Yocto: Difference between CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL and IMAGE_INSTALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333278/yocto-difference-between-core-image-extra-install-and-image-install)

but I still don't understand what's their difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`IMAGE_INSTALL` is the variable that controls what is included in any image.

`CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` is a convenience variable that enable you to add extra packages to an image based on the core-image class [1].

So if you're using an image based on core-image, adding something to `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` is just another way to add it to `IMAGE_INSTALL`. But if you're not using an image based on core-image, adding something to `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` does nothing.

Sometimes it's easy to make mistakes when adding something to IMAGE_INSTALL, like if you do `IMAGE_INSTALL += "foo"` from local.conf it would effectively replace the default lazy assignment done in core-image.bbclass resulting in a unbootable image. But doing `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "foo"` in local.conf will not break, since it doesn't have essential content being set using lazy operators.

1. https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/core-image.bbclass